# Are there any tools to transform SVG data to Canvas friendly input?

Tags: javascript, xml, svg

Are there any tools to transform SVG (XML) data to Canvas friendly input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I don't think so. SVG is actually rather different to Canvas. SVG is a vector graphics description language, whereas Canvases are programmatically "drawn" by sets of instructions. Also, Canvas isn't actually vector based at all.

Take a look at the [Raphael Javascript Library](http://www.raphaeljs.com/). Its API will draw SVG/Canvas/VML depending on the capabilities of the browser.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at canvg.  It is a JavaScript library that will parse SVG and render into a specified canvas element:

http://code.google.com/p/canvg/

There's also an Ajaxian article (but I can only post one link per post)  It's titled "CanVG: Using Canvas to render SVG files"

Comment: The Ajaxian article is here: http://ajaxian.com/archives/canvg-using-canvas-to-render-svg-files

Answer (score 1):

Dojo also has support for rendering SVG.

See the dojoX package.
[link text](http://dojotoolkit.org/projects/dojox)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this article](http://www.svgopen.org/2009/papers/54-SVG_vs_Canvas_on_Trivial_Drawing_Application/) from the svg open conference. Somewhere in the middle it discusses a method to combine svg and canvas using server side rendering.

Comment: Also have a look at the follow up article: [From SVG to Canvas and Back](http://www.svgopen.org/2010/papers/62-From_SVG_to_Canvas_and_Back/index.html), which seems to be the most complete reference on this topic I have found.

Answer (score 1):

I used Canvg as a basis to create this online tool:

[www.professorcloud.com/svg-to-canvas](http://www.professorcloud.com/svg-to-canvas)

It creates JavaScript Canvas functions from SVG input. Doesn't do the whole SVG spec, but enough to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

[Fabric.js](http://github.com/kangax/fabric.js) has an SVG-to-canvas parser. Here's a [demo](http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/). Notice how clicking on buttons in SVG section of sidebar fetches SVG documents and parses them onto canvas in real time.

You can even manipulate those canvas-rendered objects (scale, move, rotate, etc.)

Comment: @I.J.Kennedy Thanks! It's been a while since I posted this. Fabric now has its own website, docs, demos, google group, tons of new functionality and polishing of old one (e.g. that same SVG parser).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at XSLT.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can do it with XSLT, however writing the transformer isn't trivial. So I was looking for a tool that already does this for me, or something similar