# How can I draw a diminishing wavy ray or complex figures in HTML5 / Canvas

Tags: html, bezier, curve

I am trying to generate some sun 'rays' which I can best describe as looking like the blade of a krisknife, such as the blade portion of this picture. [image: this]

This is just an example.  I only need a triangular shape with two or three waves that I can close and fill.

Better yet, is there some HTML5 app with which I can draw a complex figure and then export the javascript (moveTo, arcTo, bezierCurveTo, quadraticCurveTo, ...).  Something similar to [HTML5 Bezier Sketcher](http://www.html5code.com/gallery/html5-bezier-sketcher/) but which saves the javascript.  Trying to draw complex figures blind is very difficult and I don't want to switch to SVG if it is not necessary.

Thanks 1,000,000

Edit: I have now also looked at all the options at [this site](http://javascript.open-libraries.com/utilities/drawing/10-best-javascript-drawing-and-canvas-libraries/).  None will allow me to draw and fill simple curves and then see/save canvs commands.  All that show commands show them in new libraries like fabric or jsDraw2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer among the solutions for [Convert SVG to Canvas friendly output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204431/are-there-any-tools-to-transform-svg-data-to-canvas-friendly-input).  The author didn't think it worked for him, but I think it's as perfect as any I have seen.

Professor Cloud (...is frikkin' amazing!  This isn't the first thing he's done I have found incredibly useful.) created a site to take SVG input and product Canvas output.  You can see it [here, at Professor Cloud SVG-to-Canvas](http://www.professorcloud.com/svg-to-canvas/).

Using this site, I can draw something or even take a stock vector image in AI, export as SVG, cut out the commands and past them into Prof. Clouds amazing SVG-chipper, and get Canvas code.  I understand it doesn't support full SVG capabilities, but then, neither does Canvas.  Great for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse SVG into an html5 canvas with fabric.js.
That might do the trick for you.

https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js

Beside SVG it can help you with a nice API to canvas drawing.

Comment: If I use the fabric.js, create SVG objects and parse them as fabric objects, then redo my animations using fabric, then that might accomplish my goal.  I do like the notion of importing SVG vectors, but that would be a lot of work and learning curve just to replace ten or twelve canvas curveTo commands.  The same applies to Raphael.  It's nice, but adding a huge library just because I can't plot out the quadratic equation for a wavy line seems like an elephant gun.  I need to see/draw fairly simple shapes and get lineTo, curveTo, etc...

Comment: I see your point... there's probably no escape from some math, probably a multiplication of a polynomial equation with a sine wave.

Comment: I also just saw this question once I thought to add 'parse' to my search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204431/are-there-any-tools-to-transform-svg-data-to-canvas-friendly-input.  Unfortunately, it doesn't get me any closer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is probably best but just for the record, I tried experimenting with some graph plotting, and got some nice results:
The equations are:

```
sin(x)*log(2/x) + x/10
sin(x)*log(2/x) - x/10
```

You can plot them using: http://www.graphsketch.com/

It looks good with 0 < x < 25